# float right the last item of the menu bar

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

I am trying to float the last item in the menu bar [like here](http://jsfiddle.net/1eyk7pa4/37/) back in my wordpress, but i can't manage it to make it work. is there a practical way to do this?

```
li:nth-last-child(1) {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: `li:nth-last-child(1){ float:right; }` didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just off the top of my head, I would try absolute positioning.

```
li:nth-last-child(1) {
position: absolute;    
top:0;
right:0;
display: inline-block;
}
```

You may find that absolute breaks the flow of the document, so actually, give your left top and left some padding, or if you're lazy like me... I did:

```
li:nth-last-child(1) {
position: absolute;    
top:0.5em;
right:0.5em;
display: inline-block;
}
```